# ng-click is not working with fa-icon

Tags: angularjs

`ng-click` is not working with **fa-icon**.

please see the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FteYZsU9Up1Cf8pQMSC7?p=preview)

In demo you can see when you click on fa-icon, alert will not appears, why it is not working with fa-icon.

```
<div>
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:24px" ng-click="testDcocuments(imagesB, 'imageA')" ng-class="{'unverified fa fa-thumbs-down': varified_pan_doc==0, 'verified fa fa-thumbs-up':varified_pan_doc==1 }"></i>
   <div ng-show="!verify_pan"><p>Not Verified</p></div>
   <div ng-show="verify_pan"><p>Verified</p></div>
</div>
```

In controller

```
$scope.testDcocuments = function(image, image_type){}
```

When I debug in console and make break point at $scope.testDocument, it is not stopping there

Comment: I cannot see any problem, do you have console errors?

Comment: Have you tried putting ng-click in a div that wraps the fa-icon?

Comment: which wired thing you are getting? show your code, show your page, show the issue

Comment: You probably need to wrap this on a div.

Comment: @Petran I already wrap this in div..

Comment: But you are not calling testDcocuments you are calling verifyDcocuments

Comment: @Petra, sorry it was mistaken typed, now I updated document, have a look,  and also add one demo..

Comment: You have no controller in your demo. You can't just start working with an undefined `$scope` variable and expect it to work. See the error in the console ~ *"Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code to have a controller, you had a reference error as Phil has pointed out in the comments.

http://plnkr.co/edit/c5AyzFAqjcc3xOAMV3AA?p=preview

Wrap you logic in a controller first:

```
     angular.module('sample', [])
      .controller('testController', function($scope) {
        $scope.verifyDcocuments = function(a, b) {
          alert('tt');
        }
        $scope.test = function() {
          alert('Hello');
        }
      })
```

Now you can refer to these from your template.

```
   <div ng-app="sample">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
      <div>
        <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:24px" ng-click="verifyDcocuments(rc_images, 'rc_image')" id="rc_image" ng-class="{'unverified fa fa-thumbs-down': varified_rc_doc==0, 'verified fa fa-thumbs-up':varified_rc_doc==1 }"></i>
      </div>
      <p ng-click="test()">Test</p>

      <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
      <p>Name :
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here">
      </p>
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is not exhaustive by any means, but hopefully it provides you some direction